# How to connect bluetooth devices via A4 protocol in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

I am working on connectivity of bluetooth device and for encoding and decoding I have to use protobuf. The bluetooth devices are A4 protocal supported.

After dragging 'google" & 'Proto' folder, xcode is throwing multiple error.

like "#include  File not found" but the file is already there in project.

As most of the codes are written in C++.

I tried all possible senario to fix these but unable to fix the errors.

So, Anyone can share a working sample or the solution to fix the issue will be really helpful.

Also If there is any other way to connect and retrive data from external devices, please feel free to share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/mingchen/protobuf-ios which is available on CocoaPods?

Comment: Do the devices support Bluetooth Low Energy?  The GATT profile is the only Bluetooth profile available to iOS apps without working through the MFI program